# apt-config dump not returning cache information?

Tags: apt, package-management, aptitude

From `man apt.conf`,

> Cache-Start, Cache-Grow, Cache-Limit
> APT uses since version 0.7.26 a resizable memory mapped cache file to store the available information.  Cache-Start acts as a
> hint of the size the
> cache will grow to, and is therefore the amount of memory APT will request at startup. The default value is 20971520 bytes (~20
> MB). Note that this
> amount of space needs to be available for APT; otherwise it will likely fail ungracefully, so for memory restricted devices this
> value should be
> lowered while on systems with a lot of configured sources it should be increased.  Cache-Grow defines in bytes with the default
> of 1048576 (~1 MB)
> how much the cache size will be increased in the event the space defined by Cache-Start is not enough. This value will be applied
> again and again
> until either the cache is big enough to store all information or the size of the cache reaches the Cache-Limit. The
> default of Cache-Limit is 0
> which stands for no limit. If Cache-Grow is set to 0 the automatic growth of the cache is disabled.

If Cache-Limit is preset to zero, which implies Cache-Limit to be unlimited. And if, along with it, Cache-Start and Cache-Grow are too set to some defaults. Then why does not
apt-config dump capture this info. Grepping for below gave no result.

```
$ apt-config dump | grep -E "Cache-Start|Cache-Grow|Cache-Limit"
```

Answer (score 1):

These values are some kind of fallback which get set when there is no desired configuration in place. If you look into source code:

> apt-pkg/pkgcachegen.cc

```c
map_filesize_t const MapStart = _config->FindI("APT::Cache-Start", 24*1024*1024);
map_filesize_t const MapGrow = _config->FindI("APT::Cache-Grow", 1*1024*1024);
map_filesize_t const MapLimit = _config->FindI("APT::Cache-Limit", 0);
```

`FindI` Looks for the setting in configuration space, if it's not there it set the default value.

> apt-pkg/contrib/configuration.h

```c
int FindI(std::string const &Name,int const &Default = 0)
```

And `apt-config dump` only dumps the configuration space. Your config should be there to appear in outputs which it's not. And it's obvious that `apt-config` is not able to go and look into its own binaries to find out what are the default values.

---

You might say, well there are other lines in dump which I can't find any configuration file related to them. like this one:

```
Binary::apt::APT::Cache::ShowDependencyType "1";
```

Again if we look into source code we find:

```c
_config->CndSet("Binary::apt::APT::Cache::ShowDependencyType", true);
```

In this case, this one is being configured. `CndSet` is conditional set. It sets some default configs without overwriting the existing ones.

---

So there are two things to keep in mind here.

1. There is a function which looks for a config and if it was not able to find it considers a default (Fallback) value for it.
2. There is another function which actually is manipulating a set of configurations giving them some values.